# Using BufferedWriter and DataOutputStream in java together

Tags: java, android

How can I simply write big-endian typed data into an OutputStream and still use buffering? (I'm developing for android if it makes any difference)

I tried

```
out = new BufferedWriter(new DataOutputStream(new OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream())));
```

but it looks like I'm in no luck, because this cannot be done. I'm new to Java.

Comment: If this would be an answer, I'd accept it! `out = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream()));` works like a charm! thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writers are used to write characters (text). Streams are used to write bytes (binary).

You can wrap a Stream with a Writer, but not the reverse.

If you want binary data and buffering, use a BufferedOutputStream.

Comment: [WriterOutputStream](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/output/WriterOutputStream.html) would of course disagree slightly - or any other implementation based on a `ByteBuffer` and `CharsetDecoder` pair.